# Customize Wiki Page With Specific Editable Information

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

Complete newbie question, just started working with SharePoint through Office 365  yesterday.

I'm trying to create a Wiki page for my company, where the user adds information for a program they're working on in a unique page. I would like the user to be required to fill out specific information for their project (date, time, program, description, etc). Since multiple users will be adding their own project information, I want all information to be aggregated in a table format that is **searchable** by other users. Additionally, having admin abilities for approval of the projects would be ideal.

So far, I've tried creating a wiki library to the "homepage" where pages can be added, but I keep having pitfalls with that (ie,, the columns I create aren't showing up, among other things). I'll appreciate any help/advice, even just somewhere decent on where to start understanding how to build wiki pages through SharePoint. Or anything about how to use SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to organize content so users can find things in SharePoint. For what its worth a wiki page is simply for content and can be used for the home page of your site. I like to think its similar to Wikipedia where there are key words that can be turned into new pages when you add double brackets onto them. Here is more info on [Wiki Libraries](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-and-edit-a-wiki-DC64F9C2-D1A2-44B5-AC59-B9D535551A32)

If you would like to capture specific information browse some of the "Apps" you can create on the site as there are many preset lists you can use to capture data. If your starting from scratch a "custom list" App is useful to create a basic form in SharePoint. More info: [Introduction to Lists](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Introduction-to-lists-0A1C3ACE-DEF0-44AF-B225-CFA8D92C52D7)

A copy of the list you create can be added to your Wiki home page later in something called a "web Part". You can edit your home page and insert your list as a App Part and configure how your users interact with it from the home page. [About Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Use-the-List-and-other-Web-Parts-03044488-c0e4-4226-a8fb-4cd8364424fa)